# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value in case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting this error when I run the case statement below. I think I have to convert at some point, but not sure where or how.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'reassign' to data
>   type int.

```
,(CASE WHEN Mstime <=10 THEN CAST('reassign' as varchar(30) )
            WHEN Mstime >=10 THEN Mstime END ) as TimeGroup
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the `else`, not the `then` (it is already a string):

```
(CASE WHEN Mstime <= 10 THEN 'reassign'
      WHEN Mstime >= 10 THEN CAST(Mstime as varchar(30))
 END) as TimeGroup
```

The problem you are facing is that the `ELSE` returns an `INT`.  By the rules of type compatibility, SQL Server attempts to have the `CASE` expression return an `INT` instead of a string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `cast()` `Mstime` to `varchar(30)` if that is the datatype you want to return for that expression.

```
,(case when Mstime <=10 then cast('reassign' as varchar(30) ) 
      when Mstime >=10 then cast(Mstime as varchar(30) )
      end ) as TimeGroup
```